# Edit HTML files from the command line

Tags: command-line, html, text-formatting

I'm looking for a way to edit HTML files from the command line similar to `sed` or `awk`, but using path expressions similar to `jq` or [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup). In particular, newlines, white space and other formatting details shouldn't matter.

So I'd like to say something like "delete everything between `<body>` and first `<p>` tag following it, and replace it with the this text" or "replace every `<b>`...`</b>` with `<p font-style=italic>`...`</p>`, keeping the text in between". The rest of the document should remain unchanged.

A library for, say, Perl, Python or Haskell where I can do that easily with a few lines would also be fine (but I'd prefer a commandline tool).

Background: I want to use this to clean up lots of epub files with awkward formatting, bad language tags etc.

Comment: I use `tidy` to format html to one tag-per-line, and perl to process the tags.  There are a few applications which do a more sophisticated job, but the majority have technical problems glossed over by their developers.  Someone is certain to recommend one of those.

Comment: Cleaning up formatting is one thing, and can be from the command line with utilities like [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) - which has a python script in its repo. or pandoc can do this.  but to replace elements in a way which can handle unusual blank characters really needs a full HTML parser. I dont know of any way that you could limit the commands to one line shell statements either - you would need to write a script

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I'd like to avoid re-formatting to one tag per line, and even then I'd have to deal with stuff like nesting using Perl etc.

Comment: [xslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) is the best too to do xml transformations, simple edits are possible with editors like ed, sed, vi however it can very quickly become unmanageable doing what would be simple in a transformation in what is intended as a text editor.

Comment: .. Why don't you use what you have suggested, jq or pup ? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @XTian: jq or pup can *extract* a part of the document, but they can't *change it in place*. Or if they can, I don't know how.

Comment: redirect output to new file, if all is ok, then copy on top of original

Comment: @XTian: Please give a concrete example for "replace every `<b>...</b>` with `<p font-style=italic>...</p>`, keeping the text in between". I can select all `<b>..</b>`, but how do I copy "on top of original"? Manually, for each occurence?

Comment: No!, did you read about the tool I gave a link to ? Read about how to create a style sheet [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex2).

Comment: Yes, xslt looks like it can do that, I'm still looking into it. My comments referred to "why don't you use jq or pup"? `jq` or `pup` can't do it, or I don't know how: not by redirecting output to a new file, and not in any other way I can think of. Testing `xslt` output by first sending it to a new file, and then overwriting the old file is trivial, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Here in 2022 you can use `xmlstarlet` to edit HTML files that are not strict XML. Let's call your file `index.html`; the command invocation to generate strict XML from HTML is then `xmlstarlet fo -H index.html 2>/dev/null`. However, the rest of your question is hard in generality but specific requirements should be possible. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645582/100397 for one example

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that would do what you want and it would be a lot of work to build something.  For starters you'd have to build a compiler, using *yacc* or some such, to parse your commands and then pass them on to other code to actually do the transformations.

*XLST* might work but I doubt it.  It's sitting on top of XML and HTML is too irregular a markup language to fit inside that rigid syntax: especially if you start dumping CSS on top of it.

I'd go with the *Perl* **HTML::Parser** library (or maybe one of its friends in the **HTML** module tree if they have a specialized tool for a common task of yours).  It parses HTML documents into a little internal database tree and then you can manipulate that and dump it back out.  I use it all the time to do things such as: get rid of all *iframe* tags and contents; get rid of **all** HTML tags but print out something close to the intended formatting in plaintext; and really complex *screen scraper* engines.

It's really simple to use and does all of the heavy lifting for you.  See the *CPAN* page for examples.  The distribution also comes with more examples to do things like strip out certain tags/elements and/or attributes.

Remember that back in the Stone Age *Perl* ruled the Web and was mostly concerned with slinging HTML around so the Perl Monks have been sharpening their HTML tools for decades now.