# manipulating html strings in bash

Tags: bash, html

So I have three lines from a html file:

```
/html> 
<table style="width:500px;text-align:left;">
<tr><td>apple</td><td>400</td><td>432</td><td>730</td></tr>
```

I need to somehow get the three digits visible in the third line (400, 432, 730) and assign the sum (1562) to its own variable called apple_num. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The information given about the fact that it is an html file is... well : Useless! Much, much more important would be to know its associated charset attribute as well as the charset the LANG settings in the environement your bash is running.

Comment: Related [Search pattern between tags in html](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645582/100397)

Comment: Is that ... part of ... a *closing* HTML tag *before* the data? This seems like a fragile approach at best...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search pattern between tags in html](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645559/search-pattern-between-tags-in-html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what characteristics of this file will be unchanging. Can we assume you _always_ want all groups of digits present in the 3rd line? Or perhaps on the last line? Will there always be exactly 3 sets of integers? Will the line of interest always start with `<tr><td>apple</td><td>`? Can there be more matching lines? Can you ever have numbers inside any tags like `<td style="width:500px">400</td>?` While it is possible to use a naive approach instead of a proper parser, we cannot know what approach would work without more details.

Comment: Is using a scripting language like perl, python, tcl, or whichever language of choice you want, an option? The '<' and '>' common in HTML is a sure way to confuse the shell with I/O redirection unless you carefully quote and escape them. Aside from that, I have nothing to add which others have not already answered or commented.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xmlstarlet` to parse the XML and pick out the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th `<td/>` element values. If you have other tables and table rows you'll need to provide more of your HTML or else work out yourself how to pick out the appropriate section.

Code segment for parsing `page.html`

```
apple_var=$(
    xmlstarlet fo -H page.html |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'concat(//td[2],"+",//td[3],"+",//td[4])' -n 2>/dev/null |
    bc
)
echo apple_var=$apple_var
```

Output

```
apple_var=1562
```

The first invocation of `xmlstarlet` parses the HTML and converts it as best it can to XML. The second invocation parses that XML and extracts the required `<td/>` element values, along with `+` symbols between them. The final part of the pipeline performs the maths, giving the result value you want. This is assigned to `apple_var` as required.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how flexible your input could be.

If we assume that

1. the numbers are always on the 3rd line,
2. the numbers are always integers,
3. the 3rd line contains no other digits than the ones we need,

then it could be as easy as

```
apple_num=$(sed -n '3p' file.html |       # output the 3rd line
            grep -Eo '[0-9]+' |           # extract all integers and output then one per line
            awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}')  # output sum of all the numbers
```

However this approach is **very** fragile. For example, it would fail on `<tr><td>apple</td><td>400</td><td style="color: #010203">432</td><td>730</td></tr>` (because `010203` in `style="color: #010203"` would be also recognized as a number) and even on `<tr><td>mars1</td><td>400</td><td>432</td><td>730</td></tr>` (because `1` in `mars1` would be recognized as a number).

Of course, you could furthermore precise the restrictions, e.g.

```
apple_num=$(sed -n '3p' file.html |       # extract 3rd line
            egrep -o '>[0-9]+<' |         # extract only parts like >123< (one per line)
            egrep -o '[0-9]+' |           # extract integers (one per line)
            awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}')  # output sum of all the numbers
```

but the more you precise it, the less readable this becomes. So, generally you should prefer a more generic approach like [the one proposed by roaima](/a/646792), while grep/sed/awk approach can be used only in a temporary fast-and-dirty oneliners.

Comment: thanks for the reply! How would I then assign this to a variable?

Comment: @NigelWash, I've changed the code to make the output assigned to `$apple_num`.