# How to fetch first regex result from file using bash, grep or sed?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, html

I have a file called `index.html` and I `grep '<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">' index.html` getting this:

```
<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">39.2 %</td>
<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">56.6 %</td>
```

I need to get only 39.2. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You mean you want the whole line `<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">39.2 %</td>` or just `39.2`?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have GNU `grep`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk just 39.2

Comment: @terdon Ubuntu 18. Yes, I have GNU grep

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646792/100397

Comment: Use `pup`, a html parser tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you can use `-m 1` to exit after the first match.  e.g.

```
grep -m 1 '<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">' index.html
```

From `man grep`:

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>
> Stop reading a file after `NUM` matching lines.  If the
> input is standard input from a regular file, and `NUM`
> matching lines are output, grep ensures that the standard
> input is positioned to just after the last matching line
> before exiting, regardless of the presence of trailing
> context lines.  This enables a calling process to resume
> a search.
>
> When grep stops after NUM matching lines, it outputs any
> trailing context lines.
>
> When the `-c or` --count`option is also used, grep does not output a count greater than NUM.  When the`-v`or`--invert-match` option is also used, grep stops after
> outputting NUM non-matching lines.

To then extract just the value, pipe it into sed.  e.g.

```
$ grep -m 1 '<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">' index.html |
    sed -e 's/^[^>]*>//; s/ %.*//'
39.2
```

Or, forget about `grep` and do the whole thing in `sed`:

```
$ sed -ne '/<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">/ {s/^[^>]*>//; s/ %.*//p;q}' index.html 
39.2
```

You really ought to use a HTML parser, though.  Using regular expressions alone on structured data like HTML, XML, JSON, etc is doomed to failure.

Comment: I need to get 39.2

Comment: The correct answer is "use a HTML parser".    The quick-and-dirty hack is to pretend that HTML is a line-oriented format that can be reliably processed with simple awk or perl or sed line-oriented scripts and hope that what works today won't break tomorrow.   e.g. pipe the output from `grep` above into `sed -e 's/^[^>]*>//; s/ %.*//`

Comment: `index.html` is a gcov & lcov & genhtml output. I am sure this won't break for a long time.

Comment: I recommend using `pup` for html parsing, instead of core utils.
`pup 'td[class="headerCovTableEntryLo"] -f index.html | head -1` ought to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the HTML using an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`.

```
xmlstarlet fo -H page.html |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//td[@class="headerCovTableEntryLo"][1]' -n 2>/dev/null |
    tr -dc '[:digit:].\n'
```

Output

```
39.2
```

The first invocation of `xmlstarlet` parses the HTML and converts it as best it can to XML. The second invocation parses that XML and extracts the first `<td/>` element value with an attribute `class` matching `headerCovTableEntryLo`. The final `tr` removes the space and percent characters from the string (actually, it removes everything except digits, the dot, and newline).

If you need a more precise match you will need either to make the `//...` path more specific or post more of the HTML.

If you want to avoid the call out to `tr` you can return the element value upto but excluding the first space (so `39.2 %` will be returned as `39.2`):

```
xmlstarlet fo -H page.html |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'substring-before(//td[@class="headerCovTableEntryLo"][1], " ")' -n 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `grep` , you can use the `-P` option to enable Perl Compatible Regular Expresions which give us the `\K` regex command which means "ignore anything matched up to this point". Combined with `-m1` to stop at the first match and `-o` to print only the matching portion of the line, you can do:

```
$ grep -m1 -oP '<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">\K[0-9.]' file
39.2
```

Or, similarly:

```
$ grep -m1 -oP '(?<=<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">)[0-9.]+' file
39.2
```

Alternatively, with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[> ]' '/<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">/{print $3; exit}' file
39.2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Isaac. I changed to `[0-9.]` which I was already using in the second one, but had forgotten to fix the first one.

Answer (score 0):

To complete all the tools grep, awk and sed:

`sed  -En '/<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">([0-9.]+).*/{s//\1/p;q}'`